# PostgreSQL error: 'Address already in use 0x00002740/10048'

Tags: postgresql, connection

I'm running an application in a high traffic production environment in a PostgreSQL database. I have about 850-900 open connections at a time. Every day I get some errors from end users:

> Could not connect to server: Address already in use (0x00002740/10084)
> Is the server running on host "XXXXXXXX" and accepting TCP/IP
> connections on port 5432?

When they try again they are able to open the connection.

This application is running at other clients too. Open connections there are lower and I don't have the issue there.

I'm not using PgBouncer.
Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know much about Postgres, but in general it sounds like this: You may be running out of ephemeral ports on the client (they take several minutes to be ready for use again). This is an indication that something is opening _tons_ of connections on the client, usually unnecessarily. Make sure to keep connections alive and reuse them for as long as you can instead of closing them and opening a new one next time. Users can also enlarge the ephemeral ports range but it's not recommended, that would be like just removing the warning light, also it's an OS-wide setting.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction.
The customer is using a citrix server. In our application, the connection stays open until the application closes, but there are several smaller application which open en close for small transactions (quickly save a mail, ...). 

With 'enlarging the ephemeral ports' you mean the ports on the client side (Citrix server in this case), not the database server?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.